# How can I play European versions of games on my American Nintendo 64?

Tags: nintendo-64

I have an American Nintendo 64 but I bought European games to play in French. I have the converter but it doesn't work well.

For instance, The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time only loads black and white and  Conker's Bad Fur Day doesn't work at all.

What do I need do to play to make these games playable in French. Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the American and European version of the N64 console are small but they are different. The biggest difference is American consoles use the NTSC video standard and the European console is designed for PAL. I'm a little surprised that Zelda worked at all, but not surprised that there were issues with the picture.

You need a European N64.
I understand there were a couple of models released in France, but really any N64 from Europe should work.